# Presto Jdbc Connection gives Error executing query

Tags: mysql, jdbc, presto, presto-jdbc

We are trying to execute presto jdbc connection .
We have followed the simple example in

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_presto/apache_presto_jdbc_interface.htm

- Added the jar ,
- run as java application in eclipse .

note :

- Presto is installed in the linux server . presto cli is working fine in the linux . Started presto in linux .
- We are running this class in Windows machine  eclipse ide.
  We have no firewall  in the linux machine .
- Mysql is also installed in the linux machine . We are able to access mysql in windows using java code . but unable to do it from windows .

Also tried adding ssl =true as shown below
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:presto://19.255.24.127:8080/mysql/tutorials?user=root&password=Redcar88!&SSL=true");

Exception :
java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:279)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:228)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.executeQuery(PrestoStatement.java:77)
at testdbPresto.PrestoJdbcSample.main(PrestoJdbcSample.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.JsonResponse.execute(JsonResponse.java:154)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClientV1.(StatementClientV1.java:130)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClientFactory.newStatementClient(StatementClientFactory.java:24)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.QueryExecutor.startQuery(QueryExecutor.java:46)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoConnection.startQuery(PrestoConnection.java:717)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:240)
... 3 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:174)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1279)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:299)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.OkHttpUtil.lambda$basicAuth$1(OkHttpUtil.java:91)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.OkHttpUtil.lambda$userAgent$0(OkHttpUtil.java:77)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.JsonResponse.execute(JsonResponse.java:131)
... 8 more

config.properties of presto installation .
[image]
In the code i'm using the ip of the machine as Host .

Comment: Are you getting same error with latest [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) release](https://trino.io/download.html)?

Comment: Hi @PiotrFindeisen, Thanks for responding . Yes I have used Trinojdbc driver . Even then i have the same error. Is there anything to be added on the config.properties file of Presto Installation . Any property in anyfile . I'm able to use Presto   cli and query in the Linux machine .But when accessing from another machine via  code /dbviusualizer . I have this issue . I have added config.properties screenshot  file above . can you help me understand if i missed any .  Thanks

Comment: "Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message" - did you add `SSL=true` to your connection string despite the server running without SSL/TLS?

Comment: Hi @PiotrFindeisen  Yes , I have added. code package testdbPresto;
 String url = "jdbc:trino://78.100.451.37:8080/mysql/tutorials";
  Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.setProperty("user", "root");
 properties.setProperty("password", "Passowrd!");  properties.setProperty("SSL", "true");
   Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      String sql=  "select auth_id, auth_name from mysql.tutorials.author"; 
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: To use SSL you need to enable SSL on the coordinator. See https://trino.io/docs/current/security/ldap.html#trino-coordinator-node-configuration .  Without SSL you can access your Trino without password (remove `SSL` and `password` properties). You can get more troubleshooting help on the [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) Slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).